# The cursor position in a file is not persistent form a previous editing session. Only when the file is located in a long path

Tags: bash, vim, emacs, vi, vim-plugin

For a file located in a long path, I have noticed that
the cursor position (from a previous editing/opening session), is not persistent.

Having taken the actions reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223018/vim-is-not-remembering-last-position) and [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session), the problem still appears.

Running this `script.sh`, is a minimal working example that would allow you to reproduce the same problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

# We create a `test.txt` file:
echo "Hello,

this is line

this is line 5

this is line 7
" > test_file.txt

# We declare a long path directory:
long_path_dir=testing_long_path/mksj/jfhgbus/jfhgdbhsio/kjihu_ijku_okjih/kjhui__okjikol__kjhikjn__/kjnjkmloipokl/polkjioplkmn/lkjiopk/llkkmjilpoi/kkklmn__kojuo/klkjoip_plko/ppplkojiun/klklkjmkiolp___okjn/mnhgfvghbjuio/lkmnjko/MKJNKIL_l/kjhgbhnjmki__jdjdm/kFGESCE_igjhdjd/JDJDKCNS_jdjd/jfjfj_KAJK/lkdjwnmckdjcnm/lsksjiowp___HSNKAL/mCNSJSIEO/ksjcnmsjs/KJSIL/jfhns_OSKL/ksmcmkfjnv_lksjCKSL/kfjdhnbjk_KJSH/KSJAILMK_opoijt/kdjkflmsnkjdu_LALALKJSN/NJNJKS_kskslkmcnbsm/ksjskjnjc/kioikrjsnm/kioikjui/jshncmsjkl/klkopo/NCBCNMA/mkmjnks/ksksmk/klkjh/kioskmnxl/lolOIJS/LOKSJNK/jsojs/mkmcnjkjsu/lolwos/kmkmJKJS/LOLOSPLS/lolskija/lskjmcml/lolksjfh/kjdjskn/LOLXnjijs/laSHHS/lsksmcl/lslsopolsn/lmknf/KSJAO/lolfngi/LOLSNL/lolsnzzjs/mkmdnaj/ldldpokng/lsksiks/lomxkksjm/KSLSKML/kdjdnxjfjfnk/mkmsj

# We create this directory (first remove it, in case it exists):
rm -Rf $long_path_dir
mkdir -p $long_path_dir    

# We move the test_file.txt to that directory:
mv test_file.txt  $long_path_dir
```

Once this script has runned, we open the `test_file.txt`:

`vim testing_long_path/.../.../test_file.txt`

and navigate to the 5th line:

[image]

When we quit the file `:q`, and open it again, the cursor is no longer located in the 5th line, but in the 1st line:

[image]

This also happens with `emacs`.

My `/etc/vim/vimrc` has uncommented these lines:

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

**Update 1:** Using @Sergio 1st suggestion:
I did not have a `~/.vimrc` file. I have created one in which I have written the following:

```
" Tell vim to remember certain things when we exit
"  '10  :  marks will be remembered for up to 10 previously edited files
"  "100 :  will save up to 100 lines for each register
"  :20  :  up to 20 lines of command-line history will be remembered
"  %    :  saves and restores the buffer list
"  n... :  where to save the viminfo files
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo

function! ResCur()
  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`"
    return 1
  endif
endfunction

augroup resCur
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
augroup END
```

When closing and opening again with `vim testing_long_path/.../.../test_file.txt`, the position of the cursor is not remembered.

**Update 2:** Using @Sergio 2nd suggestion:
The output of `:scriptnames` is the following, in which the `/etc/vim/vimrc` is not listed.

[image]

**Update 3:** When opening the file via `vim testing_long_path/.../.../test_file.txt`, and asking for `:autocmd BufWinEnter` I receive:

[image]

Comment: You could define a function that restores the cursor position after closing a file. See `ResCur()` function in: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session

Comment: Alternatively use the command `:scriptnames` to check if your file `/etc/vim/vimrc` has been sourced. If it is not listed, then save your initialization commands  in `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: What is the output of `:echo has('autocmd')`?

Comment: @romainl Thanks for your comment. When opening the file via `vim testing_long_path/.../.../test_file.txt`, and asking for `:echo has('autocmd')`, the output is the number `1`.

Comment: @Sergio Thanks for your comments. I have followed your 1st and 2nd suggestion, see updated post.

Comment: @DavidC. If you do `:autocmd BufWinEnter`  a line with `* call ResCur()` should be displayed. Is this line displayed for you?

Comment: @Sergio Yes, it is displayed, in the form I am showing on **Update 3** in the post

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs, the mechanism to store file positions is called `saveplace`. It can filter the files for which positions should be stored. See the documentation of the variable `save-place-forget-unreadable-files`

> Non-nil means forget place in unreadable files.
>
> The filenames in save-place-alist that do not match
>   save-place-skip-check-regexp are filtered through file-readable-p.
>   If nil, their alist entries are removed.

Now, let's see that `file-readable-p` says about your file:

```
(defvar the-long-file)
(setq the-long-file "testing_long_path/mksj/[omitted for brevity]/mkmsj/test_file.txt")

(file-readable-p the-long-file) ;; => nil
(file-readable-p "/etc/passwd") ;; => t
```

I can't explain why `file-readable-p` returns `nil` but at least this explains the behavior you observed. If you want to study that function, take a look at https://github.com/typester/emacs/blob/master/src/fileio.c#L2554

Since this happens in Emacs and vim, as you described, maybe it is a limitation further down in LibC or some OS limits.

Comment: thanks a lot for your research and time, but I'm afraid the problem is not solved :(

Comment: I cannot fathom why someone down-voted this excellent and informative answer.

Comment: @phils, thanks for the compliments. I guess, it's because I didn't completely answer the question. Arguably, the OP could just set `save-place-forget-unreadable-files` to `nil` and then it should work. I didn't test it now, though.

Comment: @Stefan Kamphausen I am not sure how to set `save-place-forget-unreadable-files` to `nil` and where even to start to test these things. I uniquely use `vim` and I am not used to `emacs`. I just reported that this problem also happens with `emacs` to give a more generalised post. Is it possible if you could please test this yourself? I think it is very important to understand if this issue is in fact a problem of any text editor, so that is just a OS limit.

Comment: @DavidC. if you just use vim, I guess it doesn't make sense for me to invest more time to show you how to set variables which is totally fine. Since I've also seen problems with this file in `ag`, but not in `grep`, `find`, or `ack` I assume it is something in the way the programs communicate with libC but it works in general.

Comment: @Stefan Kamphausen thanks a lot for your time and efforts. I would just like to confirm if with `emacs`, is definetively the problem solved after setting the variable?

Comment: Dear @DavidC.unfortunately I can't test this, because I can't reproduce the problem in the first place. Maybe you could try setting that variable by calling `M-x` `customize-variable` `RET` `save-place-forget-unreadable-files` and then see if the old-style UI is approachable for you? There is a toggle button there and on the State button you can activate your change for the current session only, without saving it.